# Node.JS: Map an array of objects by properties then get get intersections of an index array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, underscore.js

I'm getting an array of objects from mongoDB and I'm having trouble dissecting each object in the array by its properties. Basically I would like to get a certain subdocument and get its intersection then assign scores per index per intersection.

Here's my code so far:

```
exports.draft = function(req,res) {
    if(req.session.fb_id) fb_id = req.session.fb_id;

    function getUserQuery (fb_id) {
        //Get user
    }
    function getAllUsersQuery (prefs, callback) {
        //Get all users in database from user preferences
    }
    function getUserTracks (callback) {
        var query = getUserQuery;
        query.exec(function(err,tracks){
          callback(null, cu.tracks);
        })
    }

    function getInitialMatches (cuPrefs, callback) {
    var query = getAllUsersQuery(cuPrefs, callback);

    query.exec(function(err, users) {
        if(err) console.log("ERROR retrieving filtered users ---> " + err);
        callback(null, users);
    });
}

function mapInitialMatch (initMatch, callback) {
    var temp = {
        name: initMatch.name,
        tracks: initMatch.tracks
    };
    callback(null, temp);
}

var asyncInitMatches = function (callback) {
    async.waterfall([
        async.apply(getPreferences),
        function (cuPrefs, callback) {
            getInitialMatches(cuPrefs, callback);
        },
        function (initialMatches, callback) {
            async.map(initialMatches, mapInitialMatch, function (err, results) {
                if(err) console.log("ERROR in mapping user" + err);
                callback(null, results);
            });
        }
    ], function(err, results){
        if(err) console.log('------> ERROR in asyncInitMatches --> ' + err);
        callback(null, results);
    });
};

 async.parallel([
    async.apply(getTracks),
    async.apply(asyncInitMatches)
    ], function(err, results) {
       userTracks = results[0];
       matchesTracks = results[1];

       //I would like to get the intersection of userTracks and matchesTracks[i]
 });


}
```

Sample userTracks:

```
  userTracks = {
    "name": "Sample Name", 
    "tracks": [{
         "id": _id,
         "name": "Track name"
       }]
   }
```

I'm always getting a null/undefined result when I show it in the console. I'm also trying to use underscore.js (map, pluck, intersection). Also can you help me understand async.map and async.each?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to show only the problematic part?

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes please.

Comment: Most people may not like reading a huge chunk of code. Why don't you cut it short and show us only the code where the problem is?